# I can't add pictures to the product attribute item in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I can't add pictures to the product attribute item on my Woocomerce website. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.

1. In WP goto WooCommerce | Products | Attributes.

On the right is a list of your Attributes and their Terms.

2. Immediately below the Attribute name are two links "edit" and "delete".

Click "edit".

3. The next screen looks similar it lists all the Terms for the selected attribute.

Click "edit" under the term name.

4. On the left click the button "Upload/Add Image".

Hope this gets you what you need.

Best.

Tim